# Circumventing variance checks with extension methods

Tags: scala, covariance, generic-variance

This doesn't compile:

```
class MyClass[+A] {
  def myMethod(a: A): A = a
}
//error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value a
```

Alright, fair enough. But this does compile:

```
class MyClass[+A]

implicit class MyImplicitClass[A](mc: MyClass[A]) {
  def myMethod(a: A): A = a
}
```

Which lets us circumvent whatever problems the variance checks are giving us:

```
class MyClass[+A] {
  def myMethod[B >: A](b: B): B = b  //B >: A => B
}

implicit class MyImplicitClass[A](mc: MyClass[A]) {
  def myExtensionMethod(a: A): A = mc.myMethod(a)  //A => A!!
}

val foo = new MyClass[String]
//foo: MyClass[String] = MyClass@4c273e6c

foo.myExtensionMethod("Welp.")
//res0: String = Welp.

foo.myExtensionMethod(new Object())
//error: type mismatch
```

This feels like cheating. Should it be avoided? Or is there some legitimate reason why the compiler lets it slide?

*Update:*

Consider this for example:

```
class CovariantSet[+A] {
  private def contains_[B >: A](b: B): Boolean = ???
}

object CovariantSet {
  implicit class ImpCovSet[A](cs: CovariantSet[A]) {
    def contains(a: A): Boolean = cs.contains_(a)
  }
}
```

It certainly appears we've managed to achieve the impossible: a covariant "set" that still satisfies `A => Boolean`. But if this is impossible, shouldn't the compiler disallow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's cheating any more than the version after desugaring is:

```
val foo: MyClass[String] = ...
new MyImplicitClass(foo).myExtensionMethod("Welp.") // compiles
new MyImplicitClass(foo).myExtensionMethod(new Object()) // doesn't
```

The reason is that the type parameter on `MyImplicitClass` constructor gets inferred before `myExtensionMethod` is considered.

Initially I wanted to say it doesn't let you "circumvent **whatever** problems the variance checks are giving us", because the extension method needs to be expressed in terms of variance-legal methods, but this is wrong: it can be defined in the companion object and use private state.

The only problem I see is that it might be confusing for people modifying the code (not even reading it, since those won't see non-compiling code). I wouldn't expect it to be a *big* problem, but without trying in practice it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Well, without it there's nothing which even looks like circumventing the checks to me (as Andrey says in his comment as well). If anything, I'd add a line showing `foo.myExtensionMethod(new Object())` doesn't compile, while `foo.myMethod(new Object())` does.

Comment: I guess I did throw the baby out with the bathwater there. Restored along with your addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You did not achieve the impossible. You just chose a trade-off that is different from that in the standard library.

**What you lost**

The signature

```
def contains[B >: A](b: B): Boolean
```

forces you to implement your covariant `Set` in a way that works for `Any`, because `B` is completely unconstrained. That means:

- No `BitSet`s for `Int`s only
- No `Ordering`s
- No custom hashing functions.

This signature forces you to implement essentially a `Set[Any]`.

**What you gained**

An easily circumventable facade:

```
val x: CovariantSet[Int] = ???
(x: CovariantSet[Any]).contains("stuff it cannot possibly contain")
```

compiles just fine. It means that your set `x`, which has been constructed as a set of integers, and can therefore contain only integers, will be forced to invoke the method `contains` at runtime to determine whether it contains a `String` or not, despite the fact that it cannot possibly contain any `String`s. So again, the type system doesn't help you in any way to eliminate such nonsensical queries which will always yield a `false`.

Comment: No, you can make the `contains[B :> A]` private. And then access it via the implicit class.

Comment: @Lasf Well, in `private`, you can do whatever you want. That's exactly the point of `private`. But if it's private, then the wrapper doesn't have access to it either.

Comment: I added an example to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Lasf I added an example that shows that your type signatures don't help to rule out queries that will always yield `false`.